# How to use PHP ternary conditional operator inside PHP's mail?

Tags: php, html

In my PHP file i am sending an email (before the HTML starts) which has variables, which i have displayed successfully like `<td>' . $companyphone . '</td>`. These variables are being copied over from HTML code that is not inside of a PHP email. I simply want to "if $address2 exists show $address2".
How do i format the `if` in the context of the html body in this email ?

```
/* from HTML (not inside of PHP's mail), what i am copying to PHP's email */

<span><? echo $address1; if ($address2) echo ' ' . $address2; ?></span> 


/* PHP code to send email */

$subject = 'subject foo';
$message = '<html>
      <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>' . $address2 . '</td>
                // tried below and does not work
                <td>'if ($address2) echo  $address2 . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>'
```

Comment: i am not sure the best practice of this, but i have a very similar issue from within the same context. i am going to append the post. Please let me know if i should not have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` doesn't apply here.  You're not outputting something, you're just building a string.  Consider how you already know to concatenate a value to a string:

```
'<td>' . $address2 . '</td>'
```

Apply that same pattern, but conditionally with a ternary conditional operator:

```
'<td>' . ($address2 ? $address2 : '') . '</td>'
```

As long as the expression with the parentheses resolves to a string, it's just like concatenating any string.

Of course, as a side note, this specific operation doesn't make much sense.  If `$address2` is a string value, then it would only be "falsey" if it's empty, right?  So the end result is the same as just concatenating the value anyway:

```
'<td>' . $address2 . '</td>'
```

In your `echo` example at the start of your question, what you're conditionally outputting is a whitespace character.  But here you're just concatenating the string as-is, whether it has a value or not.

Comment: thank you that's all i needed! you're right my example was in error - i am using this to display secondary address information only if the user entered it, like "Suite 555". My post's example did not reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the ?: ternary operator:

```
/* from HTML (not inside of PHP's mail), what i am copying to PHP's email */

<span><?php echo $address1;
    if ($address2) echo ' ' . $address2; ?></span>

/* PHP code to send email */

<?php
$subject = 'subject foo';
$message = '
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>' . $address1 . '</td>
        // tried below and does not work
        <td>' . (($address2) ? $address2 : '') . '</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

echo $message;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
/* from HTML (not inside of PHP's mail), what i am copying to PHP's email */

<span><? echo $address1;?> <?php echo $address2 ? $address2 : ''; ?></span>

/* PHP code to send email */

$subject = 'subject foo';
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>$address1</td>
        // tried below and does not work
        <td>{$address2 ? $address2 : ''}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Pretty sure that ternaries don't work that way, you have to concatenate or set as a variable elsewhere.